# How do I put tabs in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with the menu bar at the top.

I know to put tab in HTML and it can be done like that:

```
<p style="text-indent: 5em;">
The first line of this paragraph will be indented about five characters, similar to a tabbed indent.
</p>
```

But my question would be how to do the similar thing inside the menu bar? Here is my code.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style>
    div.ex
    {
        width:300px;
        padding:10px;
        border:5px solid gray;
        background: white;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top: 200px;
        position: relative;
    }
    p.x {
        color: white;
        font:25px arial,sans-serif;
        position:relative;
        left:20px;
    }
    .align {
        position: absolute;
        left: 8em;
    }
    body
    {
        background-color: #ebebeb;
        top: 55px;
    }
    #rectangle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        background: deepskyblue;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 20;
    }
    input[type=button]
    {
        background-color: lawngreen;
        color: white;
    }
    #text {
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
</Style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="rectangle">
<p class="x">Home Page <a href="personal?id=${id}"><input type="button" name="sign up" value="Sign Up"/></a>
 <a href="hello">Home</a> </p>
</div>
<h1 id="text">Hello world, this is your home page.</h1>
<div class="ex">
<h1>签订</h1>
<hr>
${errorMessage}
<form action="register" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>
            ID：
            <input type="text" name="id" value="${person.id}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            密码：
            <input type="password" name="password" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            确认密码：
            <input type="password" name="password" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            姓名：
            <input type="text" name="name" value="${person.name}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            地址：
            <input type="text" name="address" value="${person.address}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            电话：
            <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="${person.phoneNumber}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="注册"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In other words, I'd like to put tabs between "sign up" button and "Home" hyperlink. Both are placed in the blue rectangle.

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: What do you mean by tabs?

Comment: I want them to be seperated using regular tabs, but I know HTML doesn't have the tab field. How can I achieve similar thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by “tab”, you really mean horizontal spacing. In that case, set a suitable horizontal margin on some element, e.g.

```
<input type="button" name="sign up" value="Sign Up" style="margin-right: 5em"/>
<a href="hello">Home</a>
```

(Your code needs fixing. For example, an `a` element must not contain an `input` element. But this does not affect the spacing issue.)

Comment: What if "<input type="button" name="sign up" value="Sign Up" style="margin-right: 5em"/>" was just a regular words though?

Comment: To create horizontal spacing between two groups of regular words, you need to wrap at least one of the groups in a text-level element, like `span`, and set right or left margin or padding on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong HTML pattern.

Use an unordered list and move the INPUT outside of the LABEL.

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" />
    </li>
  <li>
      <label for="address1">Address</label>
      <input id="address1" />
    </li>
  <li>
  ....
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
label, input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

See: http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: Irrelevant to the question asked, and a matter of opinion/style/school.